# How to apply scale rule for many columns in new dataset

Tags: r, scale

I have a next task

```
a = data.frame(a= c(1,2,3,4,5,6)) # dataset
range01 <- function(x){(x-min(a$a))/(max(a$a)-min(a$a))} # rule for scale
b = data.frame(a = 6) # newdaset
lapply(b$a, range01) # we can apply range01 for this dataset because we use min(a$a) in the rule
```

But how can I apply this when i have many columns in my dataset? like below

```
a = data.frame(a= c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
b = data.frame(b= c(1,2,3,3,2,1))
c = data.frame(c= c(6,2,4,4,5,6))
df = cbind(a,b,c)
df
new = data.frame(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
```

Of course I can make rules for every variable

```
range01a <- function(x){(x-min(df$a))/(max(df$a)-min(df$a))}
```

But it's very long way. How to make it convenient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine your scale function so it takes two arguments; One to be scaled and one the scaler as follows, and then use `Map` on the two data frames:

```
scale_custom <- function(x, scaler) (x - min(scaler)) / (max(scaler) - min(scaler))

Map(scale_custom, new, df)
#$a
#[1] 0

#$b
#[1] 0.5

#$c
#[1] 0.25
```

If you need the data frame as result:

```
as.data.frame(Map(scale_custom, new, df))
#  a   b    c
#1 0 0.5 0.25
```

Answer (score 1):

You can exploit the fact that the column names of `new` and `df` are same. Could be helpful if the order of the columns in the two dataframes is not the same.

```
sapply(names(new), function(x) (new[x]-min(df[x]))/(max(df[x])-min(df[x])))
#$a.a
#[1] 0

#$b.b
#[1] 0.5

#$c.c
#[1] 0.25
```

to put in data.frame

```
data.frame(lapply(names(new), function(x) (new[x]-min(df[x]))/(max(df[x])-min(df[x]))))
#  a   b    c
#1 0 0.5 0.25
```